# Fastq pairing of NGS R/F reads after quality trim

Tags: python, perl

Can any one help me in pairing my reverse read file with forward read files?
Below are the few lines of my read files:

**==> forward_sequences.fastq <==**

```
>SRR1561197.13.1/1
TCAAAAGGAGAACTCAATAGGCTGAACAAGTTATCTTCTGGGATTGTAATGAGAGTTGCTTCACTGCTTTGGAAGAAGAAAGCTCAT
+
JJJJJIJJIIJJIJJJIJIIJJJJJJJJJJIIIIIJJJJJJJHIJJIGJJJJJJJGIJJJJJGIIHHHHHFFEFFDEEDEDCACDDD
>SRR1561197.17.1/1
TATACAAAGCTGTCAACTTGATCTTCATACTTCTCATAAAGGACTGGTAATGTGTGGGCAGCAACGAAACCAACATATAAAACAGTC
+
HHGJJJJJJJJJJJJIJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJIJJJJJJIJJJJIIIIIIJIIHCHHFFFDDEDDDDDDEEEDCDDCCA
>SRR1561197.19.1/1
GATCAACAGTACTGGAATGGCCATCCATCACAAGTTCAGCTAAAGCAGCTCCTGTTGCAGGACCGTTTAGAATACCCCAGCAACTGT
```

**==> reverse_sequences.fastq <==**

```
>SRR1561197.4.2/2
ATAAAGACAGATGAAGATGCAATACAAATCATAAATAAAACGCTTTAAATAGTTTGAGCAACCCAAGCGCATAAGAAATTTCAATCT
+
HIJJIHGJJJJJFECHEHIIJJIGIJJIIJJJIJJJDHHIJIJJIJEHIJJJGIIIGJJICAEHFFFFDDDDDDCDDDCCADEDDDC
>SRR1561197.9.2/2
AGATGTCTGTCCTCCAGAAGATGGCATTGCCTGAACGCAGGAGAGAATATAACAATCATATAGGTTTTCATTCTTGTTTCCAATATC
+
IIIJJJIJEFJIJGHGIJIEHJJJJIGIIJJJJFIJHHIJIJJJIIJIJIIJJJHHHHHFFFFFFFFDEDEEEEED@ACCCDCCCDB
>SRR1561197.11.2/2
CAATGCAATGTGATTATCCAAGCTCACAATCTTCCTCACCGATCTGGAGTCTTGGAGCTTGGCCGCGGATTTCTTTTCGACGCCGAG
```

Comment: How does your output look like?

Comment: I tried Pairfq (https://github.com/sestaton/Pairfq) but it gave me empty files while putting all reads in unique files.

I wrote the following command:

./pairfq makepairs -f forward_sequences.fastq -r reverse_sequences.fastq -fp f_paired_1.fastq -rp r_paired_2.fastq -fs f_single_1.fastq -rs r_single_2.fastq --stats

the output was:
Total forward paired reads (1_paired.fastq) : 0
Total reverse paired reads (2_paired.fastq) : 0
Total forward unpaired reads (single_1.fastq) : 8492638
Total reverse unpaired reads (single_2.fastq) : 13525478

Comment: do you have anything for pairing these read files?

Comment: @SafinaA.R This is not valid fastq format as I commented on [seqanswers](http://seqanswers.com/forums/showpost.php?p=163560&postcount=54) and provided a solution there (to fix the record separator). Pairfq works for fasta/q, compressed or not, but no tool will work on malformed data. See the [fastq wiki entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FASTQ_format) for more info.